# Merging two videos via PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

So, I'm trying to merge two files using PHP and I've taken a look at the FFMpeg library, yet I cannot manage to merge them. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$vid1 = $ffmpeg->open('videos/vid1.mp4');
$vid2 = $ffmpeg->open('videos/vid2.mp4');
```

How do I stitch together `$vid1` and `$vid2` and save them?

Thanks

Comment: have you got any solution if yes please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate files directly by using [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

See [FFmpeg Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Usage:

```
shell_exec( "G:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i G:/ffmpeg/concatenate.txt -c copy G:/ffmpeg/phpconcatenated.mp4" )
```

`concatenate.txt` includes names of files you want to merge.

```
# Example concatenate.txt
file 'G:/ffmpeg/input.mp4'
file 'G:/ffmpeg/input_2.mp4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('videos/vid1.mp4');
$combination = $audio->concat([
    'videos/vid1.mp4',
    'videos/vid2.mp4'
]);
$combination->saveFromSameCodecs('videos/output.mp4');
```